# Oracle SQL developer lagging while editing code

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When editing and writing a more complex SQL statement in SQLdeveloper, it starts lagging to the point that it does not respond and I have to force it to close and restart it. It is happening for some months now.

Normally it starts to lag when editing the query after the query was once executed.  It can be very annoying since it happens that I have to restart it about every 10 minutes.

When it does not respond it is consuming quite a bit of ram.

Does anyone have a similar experience with this issue or just a suggestion about what to do here?

Comment: Share your complex SQL and version of sqldeveloper

Comment: I am using current version 19.2. I am not able to share the SQL statement. The statement contained more than 40 nested SQL statements, which could potentially explain the complexity and the lagging of SQL developer. The solution was to disable completion insight in the code editor.

Comment: W/o example code, we won't be able to do much in terms of improvements

Comment: I disabled as many features as I can under Tools > Preferences > Code Editor. Doing this helped alleviate the lag.